# How can object identifier be created programmatically

Tags: c#, object, instantiation

as a newbie in C#, I am looking for a solution to make the object identifiers of a class instantiation programmatically.

Suppose we have a class which is name "MyClass" and we want to make the following instances programmatically:

```
  MyClass  instganceName0 = new MyClass();
  MyClass  instganceName1 = new MyClass();
  MyClass  instganceName2 = new MyClass();
  MyClass  instganceName3 = new MyClass();
  MyClass  instganceName4 = new MyClass();
```

My problem is the procedure to produce the object identifiers instganceName0, instganceName1, ... instganceName4 programmatically.

I have written the following code to produce these identifiers in string type. But I don't know how I can use them as object identifier in a loop to use them as object identifiers in the instantiation procedures.

Any help is appreciated greatly.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string instganceName = "myClassInstance";
            string[] objectName = new string[4];
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                objectName[i] = instganceName + i.ToString();
            }

            var instganceName0 = new MyClass();
            var instganceName1 = new MyClass();
            var instganceName2 = new MyClass();
            var instganceName3 = new MyClass();
            var instganceName4 = new MyClass();
        }
    }

    class MyClass
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: You don't. You use an array (or other collection)

Comment: Why do you care about the variable names? What is the exact scenario here? Why cant you just use an array or a dictionary?

Comment: I think you need to use Collection of your class  `ICollection<MyClass>`

Comment: `List<MyClass> instgances = new List<MyClass>() { new MyClass(), new MyClass(), new MyClass(), new MyClass(), new MyClass() };`

Comment: Those are not called "object identifiers." They are *variable names*, which are compile-time symbols, and cannot be generated at run-time.  If you think about it, there would be no use to doing so anyway, since the point of a variable name is that you can reference it in code-- which is written prior to compilation time :) Use a dictionary or list instead.

Comment: @Jhon Wu: And what is an "Identifier"? If there is such an thing in C#? As I have read in C# Illustated, the "name of an object is an "identifer".

Comment: @Shahzad: The scenario is to produce C# code in a c# code generator.

Comment: @NewbieInCSharp If that's a C# code generator why do you need to write it this way, why can you just generate the source code in a string line by line?

Comment: @Shahzad: Because there are thousands of such instances. How could they be written line by line?

Comment: @NewbieInCSharp So you would just run a loop 1000 times and and generate 1000 lines of code in string. Then concatenate the string. That becomes 1000 lines of instances

Comment: @NewbieInCSharp So far, you've refused to say what your actual problem is. This is a very trivial task in a code generator: Just spit out lines 0..x: `sb.Append($"var instganceName{n} = new MyClass();");` (not useful, but that's your problem). This question is unanswerable because there's no question. You won't say what the problem is. "Code generator, code generator" -- that's not a question. I'm starting to wonder if you know what a code generator is: It produces a text file with a class definition, and you give that text file to a compiler. Is that what you're doing?

Answer (score 1):

Although this does not make sense why would you name it this way, but for the sake of the solution to your problem the best bet is to use Dictionary.

```
for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
  dictionary.Add("instanceName" + i, new MyClass());
}
```

Comment: Dictionary<string, MyClass> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, MyClass>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                dictionary.Add("instanceName" + i, new MyClass());
            }
Do you mean the aboww code? If yes, it does not produce the following objects:
instganceName0, instganceName1, ..., instganceName4 of type MyClass. It produces only a dictionary, in which the string "value" instganceName0 is associated with the type MyClass.

Comment: @NewbieInCSharp Your can't generate variable names at runtime. Your code could not use variable names generated at runtime even if it were possible to generate them. You need to take that on board. The way this is done is with some kind of collection.

Comment: Dictionary<string, MyClass> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, MyClass>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                dictionary.Add("instanceName" + i, new MyClass());
            }
Do you mean the above code? If yes, it does not produce the following objects:
instganceName0, instganceName1, ..., instganceName4 of type MyClass. It produces only a dictionary, in which the string "value" instganceName0 is associated with the type MyClass.
instganceName0 in the dictionary you suggest is not an object identifier but only a string "value".

Comment: @NewbieInCSharp as pointed out in comments too, the real question here is, why do you need to achieve this? Is there a good reason you want it this way or you are confused between implementations. I am sure that whatever you are trying to achieve is either impossible or has a very easy and elegant solution.

Comment: @Ed Plunkett: I'm going to creat the c# code in a code generator. How can then such objects be generated?

Comment: @NewbieInCSharp Are you generating code at design time, or run time? What is the actual problem you're having trouble with? Are you trying to generate code in a running application, then compile and load that code in your application, and then use those variables in the code you just compiled? That's not going to work. You could return a `List<MyClass>` from a generated method, though. If all you want to do is generate valid code and compile it, then generate valid code. If you don't know C# well enough to generate valid code, don't start with code generation as your first C# learning exercise